# Having trouble validating user input for a task manager CLI

Tags: python

What I want the function to do is prompt the user for a valid command. The list of valid commands is defined by the variable valid_cmds, which is a list of pairs, with each pair composed of an object_type and a cmds element.

The problem I'm having is that when the user enters any number of incorrect answers, it'll prompt the user for another command, as it should, but when the user finally enters a valid command, the function returns all the inputs, including the invalid ones. I suspect I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how function recursion works and how to execute it properly.

```
def collect():
    user_cmd = input("Manager Command > ")
    user_cmd = user_cmd.split(" ")
    try:
        user_cmd = [user_cmd[0], user_cmd[1], " ".join(user_cmd[2:])]

        # Checks to make sure command is valid (up to index 1)
        object_types = ["task", "folder"]
        cmds = [["new", "edit", "del", "done"], ["new", "edit", "del"]]
        valid_cmds = []
        for item in cmds[0]:
            valid_cmds.append([object_types[0], item])
        for item in cmds[1]:
            valid_cmds.append([object_types[1], item])
        if user_cmd[0:2] not in valid_cmds:
            print("Invalid input")
            collect()
    except IndexError:
        print("Invalid input.")
        collect()

    return user_cmd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is calling itself again when the input is invalid - so you wrote a recursive function. In this case this makes things more complicated than they need to be.
You should separate concerns here: `collect` already parses the user input. It should not also decide what to do when the input was invalid. This should be done outside the function.

My suggestion: Let `collect` return `None` when the input is invalid. Deal with repeatedly asking the user for valid input in a loop *outside* the function:

```py
def collect():
    user_cmd = input("Manager Command > ")
    user_cmd = user_cmd.split(" ")
    try:
        user_cmd = [user_cmd[0], user_cmd[1], " ".join(user_cmd[2:])]

        # Checks to make sure command is valid (up to index 1)
        object_types = ["task", "folder"]
        cmds = [["new", "edit", "del", "done"], ["new", "edit", "del"]]
        valid_cmds = []
        for item in cmds[0]:
            valid_cmds.append([object_types[0], item])
        for item in cmds[1]:
            valid_cmds.append([object_types[1], item])
        if user_cmd[0:2] not in valid_cmds:
            print("Invalid input")
            return
    except IndexError:
        print("Invalid input.")
        return None

    return user_cmd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        valid_command = collect()
        if valid_command:
            break

    print(f"command: {valid_command}")
```

In fact, while above code works, I would further suggest to also do the `input` part outside of `parse_command`. This would also make the function easier testable.

```py
def parse_command(cmd):
    user_cmd = cmd.split(" ")
    try:
        user_cmd = [user_cmd[0], user_cmd[1], " ".join(user_cmd[2:])]

        # Checks to make sure command is valid (up to index 1)
        object_types = ["task", "folder"]
        cmds = [["new", "edit", "del", "done"], ["new", "edit", "del"]]
        valid_cmds = []
        for item in cmds[0]:
            valid_cmds.append([object_types[0], item])
        for item in cmds[1]:
            valid_cmds.append([object_types[1], item])
        if user_cmd[0:2] not in valid_cmds:
            print("Invalid input")
            return
    except IndexError:
        print("Invalid input.")
        return None

    return user_cmd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        user_input = input("Manager Command > ")
        valid_command = parse_command(user_input)
        if valid_command:
            break

    print(f"command: {valid_command}")
```